# What is this というのに?

Tags: grammar, expressions

> もう妾の話は良い**というのに**！

What exactly is this というのに?

If context is needed, some people were making fun of her story and therefore she decided not to talk about it anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

もう妾{わらわ}の話{はなし}は良い{よい}というのに！means the same thing as もう私{わたし}の話{はなし}はいいのに！ You may not know this, but on its own のに can sound somewhat colloquial. というのに is a less colloquial synonym. Judging by the pronoun 妾{わらわ}, I would guess that the speaker is probably some noblewoman or ancient demoness from a work of fiction, who would naturally speak less colloquially than ordinary people.

（という）のに used on its own like this suggests someone is lamenting a fact.

Also, this particular use of 良い{よい} means 'It doesn't matter'. The dictionary I use gives this as one definition: 放って{ほうって}おいてかまわない。どうでもよい。

So the sentence means 'My story doesn't matter any more!'

Answer (score 6):

「～というのに！」, or more commonly and colloquially 「～って言って(い)るのに！」, is a fairly common way of expressing one's frustration or irritation, meaning "I'm telling you~~ (and why can't you understand?)!" It has almost the same meaning and usage as 「～～ってば！」; you could rephrase the sentence as 「もう私の話はいいってば！」 in an even more colloquial way.

As for the 良い, 明鏡国語辞典 says:

> よい　〘形〙
>   ⓳ 《「・・・もうー」の形で》もう必要ないといって、物事の中断や終了を宣言する。…はもう結構だ。「その話はもうー」「もめ事はもうー」

「良い(よい/いい)」 used with もう means 「必要ない」「要らない」 or 「終わりにする」, "not needed" "not necessary" or "should be ended".
So 「もう～～良い」 means "not necessary anymore" "should be ended now", i.e. "I've had enough of this!"

Comment: I'm inclined to trust you, since you're a native speaker and I'm not, but I have a bit of a doubt. Before I read the context the OP provided, my first thought for 「妾の話」 was 'talking about me', but after reading I wasn't so sure. Would you mind explaining this to me?

Comment: @Nothingatall 「妾の話」が "her story" ってことですね・・。"her story"/ "my story" を使ってうまく訳せません・・すいません。「私の話はもう終わりにします（ってば）！」みたいな感じだと思うんですが・・

Comment: Wait, I may have misinterpreted something. If by 'her story' the OP means 'her life story', then what you thought would be correct, wouldn't it?

Comment: そうですね、「話」って、自分の体験談かな？と思いました。でも「妾/私の話」ってambiguousで、「私の話はもう終わり！」は "We should stop talking about me" とも "I'll end my story" とも取れますよね・・

Comment: I'm sorry. It seems I wasn't clear enough. She was, indeed, talking about her past. However, the two people she was talking to make fun of her story. Therefore, she left after saying that sentence.

Answer (score 2):

と[い]{言}うのに (could also be と[い]{言}って（い）るのに) means

> [even though]{のに} [I say]{いう} [that]{と} ...

In the context of your sentence

> もう妾の話は良いというのに
>   Even though I'm saying I don't want to talk about me anymore [you keep going on about it]